# Why does my visualization not match my data? How do I get it to match?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linegraph

I have plotted a line graph to show growth of followers on social media over a period of 5 years. That is clearly presented by the axis of the graph. My problem is the data points of the graph do not match the dataset I used to come up with this visualization.

My question is why has this happened and how do I fix it?

Here is the dataset I have used showing the last 5 years of growth -

```
   Year     Month   Social Followers Months Years
1  2015  January  Twitter       5868    May  2015
2  2015  February Twitter       5910    Apr  2015
3  2015     March Twitter       5968    Aug  2015
4  2015     April Twitter       6042    Jan  2015
5  2015       May Twitter       6104    Sep  2015
6  2015      June Twitter       6176    Jul  2015
7  2015      July Twitter       6244    Jun  2015
8  2015   August  Twitter       6295    Feb  2015
9  2015 September Twitter       6348    Dec  2015
10 2015   October Twitter       6412    Nov  2015
11 2015  November Twitter       6468    Oct  2015
12 2015  December Twitter       6527    Mar  2015
13 2016  January  Twitter       6581    May  2016
14 2016  February Twitter       6636    Apr  2016
15 2016     March Twitter       6694    Aug  2016
16 2016     April Twitter       6758    Jan  2016
17 2016       May Twitter       6812    Sep  2016
18 2016      June Twitter       6876    Jul  2016
19 2016      July Twitter       6920    Jun  2016
20 2016   August  Twitter       7025    Feb  2016
21 2016 September Twitter       7179    Dec  2016
22 2016   October Twitter       7329    Nov  2016
23 2016  November Twitter       7467    Oct  2016
24 2016  December Twitter       7530    Mar  2016
25 2017  January  Twitter       7601    May  2017
26 2017  February Twitter       7701    Apr  2017
27 2017     March Twitter       7819    Aug  2017
28 2017     April Twitter       7887    Jan  2017
29 2017       May Twitter       8029    Sep  2017
30 2017      June Twitter       8092    Jul  2017
31 2017      July Twitter       8188    Jun  2017
32 2017   August  Twitter       8247    Feb  2017
33 2017 September Twitter       8371    Dec  2017
34 2017   October Twitter       8427    Nov  2017
35 2017  November Twitter       8501    Oct  2017
36 2017  December Twitter       8532    Mar  2017
37 2018  January  Twitter       8609    May  2018
38 2018  February Twitter       8803    Apr  2018
39 2018     March Twitter       8970    Aug  2018
40 2018     April Twitter       9061    Jan  2018
41 2018       May Twitter       9115    Sep  2018
42 2018      June Twitter       9170    Jul  2018
43 2018      July Twitter       9229    Jun  2018
44 2018   August  Twitter       9182    Feb  2018
45 2018 September Twitter       9257    Dec  2018
46 2018   October Twitter       9355    Nov  2018
47 2018  November Twitter       9365    Oct  2018
48 2018  December Twitter       9393    Mar  2018
49 2019  January  Twitter       9442    May  2019
50 2019  February Twitter       9549    Apr  2019
51 2019     March Twitter       9606    Aug  2019
52 2019     April Twitter       9658    Jan  2019
53 2019       May Twitter       9709    Sep  2019
54 2019      June Twitter       9751    Jul  2019
55 2019      July Twitter       9811    Jun  2019
56 2019   August  Twitter       9874    Feb  2019
57 2019 September Twitter       9931    Dec  2019
58 2019   October Twitter       9993    Nov  2019
59 2019  November Twitter      10044    Oct  2019
```

The following code is what I used to come up with my visualization -

```
twitter <- read.csv("//ecfle35/STAFF-HOME$/MaxEmery/Social media analysis/Twitter/follower growth twit.csv", comment.char="#", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Months <- c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')

#Create a second column with the same data so that it is not lost and we can verify that we havent mixed a month up

twitter$Months <- twitter$Month

#Make it a factor so that all months with the same name will change

twitter$Months <- as.factor(twitter$Months)

#Re-name the factor levels

levels(twitter$Months) <- Months

Years <- c('2015','2016', '2017', '2018', '2019')
twitter$Years <- twitter$Year
twitter$Years <- as.factor(twitter$Years)
levels(twitter$Years) <- Years

#Plotting the line graph

ggplot(twitter, aes(x = Months, y = Followers)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Years), colour = "grey50") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Years)) +
  ggtitle("The rate of growth for Twitter followers")
```

Here s the final outcome -

[enter image description here][1]

If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong I would appreciate that.

Comment: There is no image posted, can you please repost (just the image)?

Comment: your levels broke things. When you assigned the levels, you can see it applied them alphabetically - April - Jan, August - Feb,..., September - Dec. You should look into using a date format to build this in terms of time, as currently there is no reference to time to use

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts to rename the factors is reordering the factors into alphabetical order and not chronological order thus causing the problem.
Note: R has the built-in constants: `month.name` and `month.abv` with the months in proper order for this type of situation.

The following simplified code will properly order the data:

```
#Create a second column with the same data so that it is not lost and we can verify that we haven't mixed a month up
#Make it a factor so that all months with the same name will change
twitter$Months <- factor(twitter$Month, levels=month.name, labels=month.abb)

#Make it a factor of year
twitter$Years <- factor(twitter$Year)

#Plotting the line graph
ggplot(twitter, aes(x = Months, y = Followers)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Years), colour = "grey50") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Years)) +
  ggtitle("The rate of growth for Twitter followers")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was one argument missing here

```
twitter$Months <- as.factor(twitter$Months)
```

The code below should return what you are looking for

```
# Fake data
twitter = data.frame(Year=2015, Month=month.name, Social="Twitter",
                     Followers=round(runif(n = 12, min = 5000, max = 9000), digits = 0))
twitter = rbind(twitter,
                data.frame(Year=2016, Month=month.name, Social="Twitter",
                           Followers=round(runif(n = 12, min = 5000, max = 9000), digits = 0)))
twitter$Months = month.abb

# Make it a factor with levels corresponding to the R object month.abb
twitter$Months = factor(twitter$Months, levels = month.abb)

# Manipulate years as you were doing
twitter$Years <- twitter$Year
twitter$Years <- as.factor(twitter$Years)

# Plotting the line graph
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(twitter, aes(x = Months, y = Followers)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Years), colour = "grey50") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Years)) +
  ggtitle("The rate of growth for Twitter followers")
```

[image: rate of growth]